# Resolve filesystem paths (possibly with symlinks) with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need a way to verify whether or not a file is under a specific path.  If the path is `/var/www` and the file is `/var/www/something/something-else/file`, I need to return `true`.  If the file is `/var/www/../../etc/passwd`, I need to return `false`.

In PHP land, I usually use a function called [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.

I run `realpath()` on both the desired path and the full file path, then determine if the desired path is a substring of the result of the fully resolved file path.  If it is, I return `true`.

Is there a function for Node.js that achieves the same goal?  [`path.resolve()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) gets me half way, but doesn't handle any symlinks that are actually in the filesystem.  [`fs.readlink()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_callback) has absolutely no documentation at all, and may not directly apply since I won't always have symlinks.

Must I loop through each part of the path, resolving symlinks as I go, or is there a more canonical method?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Node also has [`fs.realpath()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_options_callback) so that should work the same way as in PHP.

Comment: note the use of realpath: `fs.realpath(the_path, options, callback)` // it uses callback.

Comment: Alternatively, use `fs.realpathSync(filepath)` which is a synchronous call which doesn't require a callback. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_path_options